# solve small symmetric triadiagonal eigenvalue problem symbolically

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, symbolic-computation, tridiagonal-matrices

I have a bunch of small ($n<20$) symmetric tridiagonal eigen problems,
$$
A x = \lambda x
$$
with $A = \text{diag}(b_i, a_i, b_i)$, $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, which I need to solve *symbolically* for eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Any hints on how to best approach this task?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks @Hellen for the reply. The Thomas algorithm solves a linear tridiagonal problem. Do you know how to extend it to solve the above eigenvalue problem?

Comment: $(A-\lambda)x=0$ is still tridiagonal and symmetric.

Comment: And how do I know $\lambda$?

Comment: Ah! You want to find the eigenvalues symbolically? No, you are out of luck.

Comment: Have you tried Cholesky decomposition? I think it won't be very hard to associate the eigenvalues of the triangular matrix $L$ and those of $L^TL$.